# Text over Appbar from unknown source

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm working on a mobile app and I'm using a scaffold to display some title but for some reason, I recently found that on some android devices, there is some text coming from an unknown source and it's displayed over my Appbar. I can't reproduce that same result on any other device or emulator.

This is how it should work
[image: How it should work]

and for some reason this is what it does

[image]

I checked to see if I have that text somewhere in my code and it's not. Another weird thing is that... that text is added only when I click the home button from the bottom bar. Again, that text is not added there from code. Already checked multiple times.

Comment: Can you share code example?

Comment: sure. The app bar is here https://codeshare.io/EB4dQO and to load the home screen I'm using this 'Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                    context,
                    HomeScreen.idScreen,
                  );'

Comment: Why are you using `SizedBox` in the `title`?

Comment: Remove that `SizedBox` & try again. Because maybe there are two or more overlapping app bars there. If you have to reduce or increase the height of the app bar, use the `PreferredSizeWidget` to set it that you're already having